# Weird issue with Laravel relation in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently facing a weird issue with one of my Laravel Models.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gallery extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $with = ['member','photos', 'cover'];

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'id', 'member')->setEagerLoads([]);
    }

    public function cover()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Photo::class, 'id', 'cover')->setEagerLoads([]);
    }

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Photo', 'photoable')->setEagerLoads([]);
    }
}
```

If I dump all galleries, each gallery has a cover which is a Instance of App\Models\Photo

```
$galleries = Gallery::all();
dump($galleries);
```

This also works with `$galleries->toJson()` and `$galleries->toArray()`

However, if I loop over galleries, cover is only an integer.

```
$galleries = Gallery::all(); 
foreach($galleries as $gallery){
   dump($gallery->cover);  // Integer instead of App\Models\Photo
}
```

While this returns a App\Models\Member:

```
$galleries = Gallery::all(); 
foreach($galleries as $gallery){
   dump($gallery->member); //Instance of App\Models\Member
}
```

Laravel: 6.6.2
PHP: 7.4

Comment: You need to combine all answers here to solve this issue. If you change `member` to `member_id`, `cover` to `cover_id` on your `galleries` table, you do not need to explicitly set `foreign key` and `local key`, and you problem is solved, imo.

Comment: why are you calling `setEagerLoads`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gallery model attribute `$cover` has the same name as `relation`.

Your model use `$cover` attribute which have integer value (foreign key to related model).

You could rename column `cover` for example to `cover_id`.

Comment: it will always return the attribute not the relationship, regardless of whether it is loaded or not ... `getAttribute` checks for the attribute before then looking for the relationship

Answer (score 2):

Relationship name cannot be the same as the column name in the table. Rename one or the other, would recommend to rename the column to `cover_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You passed the wrong place of param in a relationship.

pass it as below.

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'member','id')->setEagerLoads([]);
}

public function cover()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Photo::class,'cover','id')->setEagerLoads([]);
}
```

Here example of [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```